# How to get value from this json structure?

Tags: php, json

I have PHP code to accessing JSON:

```
$cache = './cache.json'; 
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache),true); //Decode as an json array 

if(is_array($response['data'])){ 
foreach ($response['data'] as $data) { 

if ($data['comments']['data'] != null) {  
foreach($data['comments']['data'] as $comment){ 

...
```

The code above works with this JSON Structure:

```
{
"pagination": {

},
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"data": [
    {
        "attribution": null,
        "tags": [

        ],
        "type": "image",
        "location": null,
        "comments": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "filter": "Normal",
        "created_time": "1339298544",
        "link": "http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/LrZfG6sU_l\/",
        "likes": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "users_in_photo": [

        ],
        "caption": null,
        "user_has_liked": false,
        "id": "210373896496566245_180213154",
        "user": {
            "username": "realwahyuputra",
            "website": "",
            "profile_picture": "http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg",
            "full_name": "realwahyuputra",
            "bio": "",
            "id": "180213154"
        }
    }
]
}
```

But it doesn't worked when access JSON Structure like this:

```
{
"pagination": {

},
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"data": [
    {
        "attribution": null,
        "tags": [

        ],
        "type": "image",
        "location": null,
        "comments": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "filter": "Normal",
        "created_time": "1339298544",
        "link": "http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/LrZfG6sU_l\/",
        "likes": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "users_in_photo": [

        ],
        "caption": null,
        "user_has_liked": false,
        "id": "210373896496566245_180213154",
        "user": {
            "username": "realwahyuputra",
            "website": "",
            "profile_picture": "http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg",
            "full_name": "realwahyuputra",
            "bio": "",
            "id": "180213154"
        }
    }
]
}
{
"pagination": {

},
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"data": [
    {
        "attribution": null,
        "tags": [

        ],
        "type": "image",
        "location": null,
        "comments": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "filter": "Normal",
        "created_time": "1339298544",
        "link": "http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/LrZfG6sU_l\/",
        "likes": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "users_in_photo": [

        ],
        "caption": null,
        "user_has_liked": false,
        "id": "210373896496566245_180213154",
        "user": {
            "username": "realwahyuputra",
            "website": "",
            "profile_picture": "http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg",
            "full_name": "realwahyuputra",
            "bio": "",
            "id": "180213154"
        }
    }
]
}
{
"pagination": {

},
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"data": [
    {
        "attribution": null,
        "tags": [

        ],
        "type": "image",
        "location": null,
        "comments": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "filter": "Normal",
        "created_time": "1339298544",
        "link": "http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/LrZfG6sU_l\/",
        "likes": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/7f69259cb2ab11e1989612313815112c_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "users_in_photo": [

        ],
        "caption": null,
        "user_has_liked": false,
        "id": "210373896496566245_180213154",
        "user": {
            "username": "realwahyuputra",
            "website": "",
            "profile_picture": "http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg",
            "full_name": "realwahyuputra",
            "bio": "",
            "id": "180213154"
        }
    }
]
}
```

How to modify my php code so i can access that JSON?

**-- Edit --**

Modify the question to make it validate as JSON. Look code below:
        // Collect all instagram API including next pagination value

```
    <?php 
    include('conf.php'); 
    require 'instagram.class.php'; 

    $cache = './cache_coba.json'; 

    $instagram = new Instagram($accessToken); 
    $instagram->setAccessToken($accessToken); 
    $response = $instagram->getUserMedia($userID); 

    // How to Add {"data":[ at the first file

    while ($response = $instagram->pagination($response)) {
    if($response){ 
    $opn = file_get_contents($cache); 
    $opn .= json_encode($response);
    file_put_contents($cache, $opn);
    } 
    }

    // How to Add ]} at the end of file

    echo 'finish';

    ?>

    // Below is the API Response code, how to delete {"pagination" to "data":[ at the first
    // And at the end how to delete ]} and replace to comma ,

    {"pagination":{"next_url":"https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/users\/180213154\/media\/recent?access_token=a44866ef0be\u0026count=1\u0026max_id=454315833979653858_180213154","next_max_id":"454315833979653858_180213154"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"attribution":null,"tags":["nikah","hadits","islam"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":0,"data":[]},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1368378689","link":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/ZODdgMMU7i\/","likes":{"count":4,"data":[{"username":"elvina_melati","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_173812552_75sq_1388751668.jpg","id":"173812552","full_name":"Elvina melati"},{"username":"kennethtan","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_1074913_75sq_1387989988.jpg","id":"1074913","full_name":"Kenneth Tan"},{"username":"yogiealmuchtar","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_359473314_75sq_1366691245.jpg","id":"359473314","full_name":"Yogie Al Muchtar"},{"username":"dittanggraenii","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_341887668_75sq_1384157369.jpg","id":"341887668","full_name":"\u2606\u2022Ditta AnggRaeni\u2022\u2606"}]},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com\/fc907c08bb2611e298dd22000a9f3c77_6.jpg","width":306,"height":306},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com\/fc907c08bb2611e298dd22000a9f3c77_5.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com\/fc907c08bb2611e298dd22000a9f3c77_7.jpg","width":612,"height":612}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1368378700","text":"Teruntuk calon mertuaku nun jauh disana #hadits #islam #nikah","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":"realwahyuputra"},"id":"454315929551064667"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"454315833979653858_180213154","user":{"username":"realwahyuputra","website":"","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","full_name":"realwahyuputra","bio":"","id":"180213154"}}]}
```

Comment: The second JSON snippet isn't valid JSON. Try validating your JSON first using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) or similar.

Comment: I think so. Instagram API returns with the first JSON. There's pagination properties to access next photos and returns next JSON. So im trying to combine all json returns to one flat file called cache.json with the structure like second json snippet.

Comment: That second snippet has two json objects back to back, like you just string concatenated the two json objects. You could combine the objects into an array. Something like `[obj1, obj2, obj3]`. Sorry if I am misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: You cannot create valid JSON object representations by simply appending them together.

Comment: Your json needs to look like this - http://pastebin.com/00V7TRcn

Comment: Yes the second snippet has three json objects combined in one file. If i cant appending them together, something like make them in separate files will works? But is there a way to do that?

Comment: i updated the question to make it validate to json

Answer (score 0):

Your second file actually contains 2 separate JSON arrays.

You need to add an array key to each of those so it can parse the whole contents of the file as a single JSON array.

Change this:

```
{
"pagination": {

},
"meta": {
    "code": 200
} 
etc.....
etc.....
```

into this:

```
{
0 : {
    "pagination": {

    },
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    etc....
    etc....
1 : {
   "pagination": {

    },
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    etc....
    etc....
}
```

Then you can parse the whole cache as a single JSON array.
Like so:

```
$cached_results = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache),true); //Decode as an json array 
foreach($cached_results as $response) {
    // continue with your normal code
    if(is_array($response['data'])){ //etc....
}
```

Comment: i updated the question to make it validate to json, see above.